# JQuery: slide not working as expected

Tags: jquery, show, slide

This will hopefully be a simple one:
I have a div I want to slide into the screen when the page loads.

I'm trying to find out why this works:

```
$(function() {
    $('.mydiv').slideDown(500);
});//END ONLOAD
```

But not this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.mydiv').show('slide', { direction: 'down' }, 500);
});//END ONLOAD
```

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

(ps: CSS is .mydiv {display:none;}

Comment: Because the string `slide` isn't a valid duration? Take a look at the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/)..

Comment: Yes, show's prototype is .show([duration],[easing],[callback]).  the only valid strings you can pass for duration are 'fast' or 'slow'. the object you send along in the easing parameter is incorrect. you need to pass a string along: "swing" or "linear".  finally, the callback method can not be a number, it's a method.  you should place the 500 value where 'slide' is now, enter a valid easing method, and remove the last parameter since you don't define a callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jquery API docs for the [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method state that the show method defintions are as follows:

```
.show()
.show( duration [, callback] )
.show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
```

where:

```
duration - A string or number determining how long the  animation will run. 
easing - A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition. 
callback - A function to call once the animation is complete.
```

the correct implementation using show would be

```
.show(500);
```

Comment: Cool thanks Jason. .show(500); works well. But how do I get it to slide form the left or right?

Comment: use animate() or the show() method I outlined from jQuery UI which accepts the effect argument

Answer (score 1):

jQuery core does not include effects for `show()` method, however jQueryUI extends `show()` with effects. Code you have displayed would require you to include jQueryUI library ( or components)  along with jQuery .

```
show( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )
```

[jQuery UI show() docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/)